# Custom location permission message not showing on iOS in managed Expo React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, permissions, expo, location

Why the custom location permission message for my iOS Expo React Native app is not showing app? I've tried adding the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key to my app.json file, but my custom message isn't showing up when the user is prompted for location access.

my app.json file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.aaa.bbb",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Allow my app to use your location to do this and that....."
      }
    },
  }
}
```

And this is how I request the permission

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    (async () => {      
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
        return;
      }

      await getCurrentLocationAndUpdateState();
      setIsLoading(false);
    })();
  }, []);
```

What happening is that the default message is being shown instead of my custom message after building the app and installing it via TestFlight.

Comment: Ensure that you request Always permission. Or try using config plugin (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#example-appjson-with-config-plugin)

Comment: I think I do, I have updated my post to include how I request the permission

Comment: I think you should use NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription instead of NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription(https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#permission-nslocationwheninuseusagedescription)

Answer (score 1):

My problem turned out to be related to me mixing between the method that gets the permission and the property to be used in the app.json

Changing the property in app.json:expo:ios:infoPlist to

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

solved the issue for me